# phantomjs and chromedriver

Tags: phantomjs, selenium-chromedriver

I have a trouble:
use `phantomjs` or `chromedriver`.
when I run autotest with chromedriver it works correctly but phantomjs throws exception at the same script in line:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById("+SelecterId+").click()")
```

text of exception:
...

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Error Message
>   => \'\'undefined\' is not a function (evaluating \'document.getElementById(3509082).click()\')\'\n caused by Request =>
>   {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"119","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:59162","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/3.3"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"sessionId\":
>   \"1f26a210-46b4-11e3-8385-173d5f6ec47a\", \"script\":
>   \"document.getElementById(3509082).click()\", \"args\":
>   []}","url":"/execute","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"execute","directory":"/","path":"/execute","relative":"/execute","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/execute","queryKey":{},"chunks":["execute"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/1f26a210-46b4-11e3-8385-173d5f6ec47a/execute"}'
>   ; Screenshot: available via screen
>
> Have any ideas how to solve this trouble?

Comment: Try `"` around the id.

Comment: i tryed. result the same - exception